# POST request to website Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, post, nsmutableurlrequest

I am trying to send this POST request to the specified website in Objective-C, but know very little about HTML and how to format my request.

The address is: https://selfservice.mypurdue.purdue.edu/prod/bwckgens.p_proc_term_date if you want to see where I am getting this HTML source code from.

```
    <FORM ACTION="/prod/bwckschd.p_get_crse_unsec" METHOD="POST">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="term_in" VALUE="201320">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="sel_subj" VALUE="CS">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="sel_levl" VALUE="dummy">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="sel_schd" VALUE="dummy">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="sel_coll" VALUE="dummy">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="sel_divs" VALUE="dummy">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="sel_dept" VALUE="dummy">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="sel_attr" VALUE="dummy">
   </FORM>
```

I am trying to send a POST request to the address https://selfservice.mypurdue.purdue.edu/prod/bwckctlg.p_display_courses with the the field "term_in" equal to 201320 and the "sel_subj" field equal to "CS", and the rest being dummy. How would I go about doing this?

This is what I have so far:

```
#import "PCFViewController.h"

@interface PCFViewController ()

@end

NSMutableData *mutData;

@implementation PCFViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)queryServer {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://selfservice.mypurdue.purdue.edu/prod/bwckschd.p_get_crse_unsec"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed timeoutInterval:3.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString *args = @"term_in=201320&sel_subj=CS&sel_day=dummy&sel_schd=dummy&sel_insm=dummy&sel_camp=dummy&sel_levl=dummy&sel_sess=dummy&sel_instr=dummy&sel_ptrm=dummy&sel_attr=dummy";
    NSData *requestBody = [args dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [request setValue:@"text/html" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:requestBody];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [connection start];
    if (connection) {
        mutData = [NSMutableData data];
    }
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
     NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[mutData length]);
    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:mutData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", str);
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"%@\n", error.description);
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [mutData setLength:0];
    NSLog(@"%@\n", response.description);

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [mutData appendData:data];
}
@end
```

My console shows me this output:

```
Succeeded! Received 213 bytes of data
2012-10-25 02:25:38.683 Purdue Course Finder[25844:c07] <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>410 Gone</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Gone</h1>
/prod/bwckschd.p_get_crse_unsechas been permanently removed from this server.</p>
</body></html>
```

Can someone help me figure out why this is not a valid request? If a value is set to dummy, should I not add it to the string? Is the string in an incorrect format with each value being suffixed with a &? Any suggestions? Can someone get me the URL of this POST request so I can modify my code accoringly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it in this format,

```
[request setValue:@"201320" forHTTPHeaderField:@"term_in"];
[request setValue:@"CS" forHTTPHeaderField:@"sel_subj"];
[request setValue:@"dummy" forHTTPHeaderField:@"sel_levl"];
```

Comment: How would I do this for multiple values? Would setting these values this way add them to my POST request or would I have to do more?

    `[request setValue:@"201320" forHTTPHeaderField:@"term_in"];`
    `[request setValue:@"CS" forHTTPHeaderField:@"sel_subj"];`

IS this all that is needed?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the answer. You need to set it this way for all the values. or else you can set it as setHTTPBody.

Comment: Perfect. So just do this for all of the fields, and then proceed and it should work as intended correct?

Comment: Yes, that is the way we normally set values in HTTP Post request. and you need rest of the code which you put above as well. Try it and let me know.

Comment: Okay. I won't be able to try this until tomorrow, as I have an exam tonight. I will mark this as the accepted answer since your response time was so quick. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The expected result is a list of CS Courses offered in Spring 2013. If you look at the html file, it's easier to understand what I am trying to do.

Comment: What is the expected result? Because if you pass the post body mentioned in your question, I am always getting this message only. Try installing a plugin like 'poster' in firefox and try to execute the post request there first. Only once it works there, you will see it working in your code.

Comment: Is this the correct link? Because I am getting the same error when i go to this link. https://selfservice.mypurdue.purdue.edu/prod/bwckgens.p_proc_term_date

Comment: My apologies. You can go here:
https://selfservice.mypurdue.purdue.edu/prod/bwckschd.p_disp_dyn_sched. Then click on Spring 2013 and proceed. Look at the source on that page

Comment: This doesn't look like a normal webservice which you can hit directly. If the link is fired directly with the above post body, this is the response being fetched always. "/prod/bwckschd.p_get_crse_unsechas been permanently removed from this server." I am not sure if you can hit this service to fetch the list in this way. The above objective c code will work fine for any webservice with a post body request. I am sorry, but in your case you need to raise this as a different issue in appropriate category. This doesnt look like an iOS related issue for me.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will post this in another section, but how should I pose the question so it's easy for everyone to understand without having to look at the HTML code? Would it possibly work if I initially started at the web page given to you, and then go from there?

Comment: Give this link( selfservice.mypurdue.purdue.edu/prod/bwckschd.p_disp_dyn_sched) and guide them to reach till the page where you want the list of CS Courses. And ask their opinion on how to get that required data by firing a webservice call in iOS like this. Also mention when you directly fire the request you are getting the above error message. If this can be achieved by firing a post request, you can use the above code posted by me to get the list.

Answer (score 3):

You need to supply the fields and their values as the body of your request, and set the content type:

```
NSString *paramString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"arg1=%@&arg2=%@", val1, val2];
NSData  *data = [paramString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request setHTTPBody:data];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

Then execute your request.

Answer (score 1):

@try this code

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://selfservice.mypurdue.purdue.edu/prod/bwckctlg.p_display_courses"];  

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed timeoutInterval:3.0];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *args = @"term_in=201320,sel_subj=CS,sel_levl=dummy,sel_schd=dummy,sel_coll=dummy"sel_divs=dummy,sel_dept=dummy,sel_attr=dummy";

NSData *requestBody = [args dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[request setHTTPBody:requestBody];

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

handle response or error with NSURLConnectionDelegate Methods

Comment: Aren't the different fields supposed to be delimited with a semicolon instead of a comma? Or is that fine?

Comment: I made a change, if you know how to fix it I would be grateful.